# Proof that if $\gcd(a,p^2)=p$ and $\gcd(b,p^3)=p^2$ then $(ab,p^4)=p^3$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

So $p =ax+p^2y$ and $p^2 =bz+p^3w$

$ax= p-p^2y$ and $bz= p^2-p^3w$

$axbz= p^3-p^4w-p^4y+p^5wy$

$abxz= p^3-p^4(w+y-pwy)$

$abxz+p^4(w+y-pwy) = p^3$

How can I say that $\gcd(ab,p^4) = p^3$ ?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: The redaction is really not so good (and not smooth to read).

Comment: It's simply $\,\nu(a) = 1,\ \nu(b) = 2\,\Rightarrow\, \nu(ab) = \nu(a)+\nu(b) = 1 + 2\ $ $\phantom{}$ by the linked *additivity* property of the $p$-adic valuation.

Comment: Just do it. $a=mp$ where $\gcd(m,p)=1$ and $b=np^2$ where $\gcd(n,p)=1$. ANd so $ab=mnp^3$ and $\gcd(mn,p)=1$ so $\gcd(ab,p^k)=p^3$ if $k\ge 3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\gcd}{\text{gcd}}$

If $$\gcd(a,p^2)=p\quad \text{and}\quad \gcd(b,p^3)=p^2,$$
then $$a=p\alpha ,\quad \text{where }\gcd(\alpha ,p)=1,$$
and 
$$b=p^2\beta ,\quad \text{where } \gcd(\beta ,p)=1.$$

Therefore $$ab=p^3\alpha \beta ,$$
where $p\nmid \alpha \beta $. And thus, the claim follow.

Comment: So my steps right?

Comment: I still confuse

Comment: The problem in what you wrote in your question it's you use a wrong result that is : "if there are $u,v\in\mathbb Z$ s.t. $au+bv=k$ then $\gcd(a,b)=k$". This is unfortunately not correct. Nevertheless, if you can prove that $k$ is the biggest integer s.t. there are $u,v\in\mathbb Z$ s.t. $au+bv=k$, then indeed $gcd(a,b)=k$ and your proof is fine. In your case, it's rather straightforward. Here, I just proposed a way to avoid this problem. @AndiDanuSetiawan

Comment: I am sorry, my question wrong. This is where i'm confuse.

Comment: How can i say gcd(a,b) = p^{3}

Comment: There is the right question

Comment: No, it's not $gcb(a,b)=p^3$ but $gcb(ab,p^4)=p^3$. You have that $abu+p^4v=p^3$. Now, if $gcd(ab,p^3)>p^3$, then necessary, $gcd(ab,p^4)=p^4$, i.e. $p^4\mid ab$. So know you have to justify that $p^4\nmid ab$, and then you can conclude that $p^3$ is the biggest integer s.t. $abu+p^4v=p^3$ for some $u,v\in\mathbb Z$ and thus that $gcd(ab,p^4)=p^3$.@AndiDanuSetiawan

Comment: Thanks again @Surb

Comment: @AndiDanuSetiawan More generally and conceptually this may be viewed as a special case of the additivity of the $p$-adic valuation, see the linked dupe.

Comment: It's true, awasome :D